# Using Regedit in Java

Tags: java, registry, regedit

How do I use regedit so as to store some deatails of my program ?
I would like to use this to store some data like the program folder, some user cofigs and also some extensions that the computer should recognize as my program's extension.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider using the [Preferences API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/prefs/Preferences.html). `Preferences.systemRoot()` should let you touch the registry node at `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\JavaSoft\Prefs` on a 64 bit computer with 32 bit java.